# How to handle different customer versions in Angular 2 app?

Tags: html, angular, architecture, multi-tenant, theming

We are developing a SaaS-application and currently facing the situation that different customers ask for different customizations. I have already googled and read a lot specifically about [Multitenancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy). I am also familiar with the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

**But** this still leaves me a bit confused about a good concept for an Angular 2+ application. Business logic is not gonna be the problem, as I can use Angular's dependency injection to load and use customized services for different customers. Also theming itself is not a problem, as we use [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) which has a nice theming engine build in. What **does give me a headache** are the templates itself. Of course I can use `*ngIf` and `*ngSwitch` within the HTML templates, but this is exactly the kind of code I want to avoid, because it will become horrifying once reaching 50+ customer versions.

Let's have a real life example. On a search-page all customers can search for objects and export single objects as a file download. One specific customer asks as to implement a mass export in a proprietary file format which needs a new button in the page, which obviously all the other customer should not see.

The three options I can think of for this scenario (and none of which I really like) are the following:

1. as mentioned before working in the template itself with `*ngIf` and/or `*ngSwitch*`
2. using the theming capabilities of Angular Material and working with css-only (`display: none;`)
3. maintaining multiple versions of the component (depending on the needs using component inheritance) and loading the correct version of the component depending on the user

All of them have obvious con's, just to name a few:

1. Nightmare to maintain once customer numbers grow and customizations become more frequent (think of a bigger component with 6 differentiations and 50 customers ...)
2. for now actually my favorite, but functionality not really disabled, just hidden (of course the back-end checks for permissions, but still more information is transferred to the users then necessary)
3. works well for the code-part of the components, but would mean to maintain massive amounts of duplicate template-code

I am sure we are not the first to tackle this issue. Am I overseeing any solution with less disadvantages? Are there any code patterns that I could apply here?

**edit:** after more discussion in our company we realized that there is another important point to this: some customers are hosted on their own servers, but most of them are being served from one central server. This means that the optional features have to detected and added at run-time, which implies some kind of awkwardness.

So our approach is to extend our existing licensing database to also contain the customer specific functionalities, which then obviously only that customer has a license for. Now the easy solution is to have a license endpoint and get all the licenses the customers has acquired, then every optional function can just sit in a simple single `*ngIf`. I appreciate that this is a simple and clean solution, but it offers the potential to find out some business facts about other customers of our company (by unobfuscating the code and finding additional endpoints etc.pp.). So probably combining this with server-side rendering would be the best solution I can think of right now.

Answer (score 1):

Of course I don't have a clear cut solution that would totally fit your scenario, but here is an idea.

1. Divide your page into components that act as container regions.
2. For each customer create a customer configuration that would say
   which atomic components goes in each region.
3. Create atomic components in which each component can be a single function isolated from the rest of the other components. Rely more on services to     communicate between them. As an example for this atomic component is the button that create the new export in your example.
4. Create your page dynamically using ComponentFactory.

I have used the same approach before to customize a design toolbox based on a slide template (like powerpoint slides templates).

As for the options you mentioned, here are my 2 cents:

1. *ngIf and *ngSwitch, you can eliminate these if u create ur components dynamically and use granular or atomic components.
2. I don't think this would be a good approach in terms of architecture
   and design. You are just manipulating the view css
3. If you use transclustion, this can minimize your code base if you
   can group the components efficiently.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Sameh! Thanks for you answer. I took some inspiration from it for my edit in my question. Basically your answer is the base of it, having a config (or licensing db) and use atomic components. I already upvoted, but will wait a little while for more answer before accepting. Cheers!